# Python / Scrapy: yield request without callback

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to enter getMonthEvents. But somehow it seems the callback is never executed. Any ideas? thanks :)

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class EventItems(Item):
    Title = Field()
    Link = Field()
    Date = Field()
    Time = Field()
    Place =  Field()
    Description = Field()
    Program=Field()

class SpiderForHSMT(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'HMTM'
    start_urls = ['http://www.some_website.com']
    rules =(Rule( LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="VER_2013_DISPLAYSEARCHRESULTS"]/table[1]/tr[3]'), tags=('a',), attrs=('href',)), callback = 'parseMonth'), )

    def parseMonth(self, response):
        request = Request(response.url, callback = self.getMonthEvents)
        yield request

    def getMonthEvents(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are replicating your request in parseMonth the requests get filtered as duplicates [(see documentation)](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects). Add `dont_filter=True` to your request so that they are not filtered.

```
request = Request(response.url, dont_filter=True, callback = self.getMonthEvents)
```